# iOS MQTT do not receive message after reconnection

Tags: ios, swift, mqtt, ios-mqtt-client-framework

I am developing an iOS application using MQTT-Client-Framework.
The app successfully communicates with the server at the first launch.

But after I turn it to background and get back to foreground, I no longer receive any message from the MQTT server.

Everytime the app resign active and become active, I will do the reconnection with a new `Mqtt` object (different client ID):

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //Unsubscribe topic, disconnect the mqtt client, and close the client
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    //Renew mqtt client, set delegate, reconnect to server and subscribe topic
}
```

However, I no longer receive any message from server after the reconnection. I checked the client status, and it is connected. How can I make the application receive message after reconnection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed myself by changing the clean session flag to false
Do not need to unsubscribe the topic